# Debugging's problems

Tags: android, debugging

I am having problems when I try to debug my Android Application.

Here is my code. The android application must show an Image took from camera.

```js
 private class buttonTakePicture implements Button.OnClickListener {
  public void onClick(View v) {
   takePhoto(v);
   }
 }
 private class buttonGalleryAccess implements Button.OnClickListener {
  public void onClick (View arg0) {
   Intent accesGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
   startActivityForResult(accesGallery, SELECT_PICTURE);
  }
 }
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {
    try {
      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Proyecto/"+"foto.jpg");
      imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
      //imageView1.setImageBitmap(detectarObjecto(bitmap)); 
      // bitmap.recycle();
    }catch(Exception e){
     Log.v("ERROR BITMAP",e.toString());
    }
  
   }  
  }
 private void takePhoto(View v) {
  //Creating the intent to call the camera
   Intent intent = new Intent (android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   //Creating a folder to store our images
   File carpetaImagenes = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Proyecto");carpetaImagenes.mkdirs();
   //We name our image
   File nombreImagen = new File(carpetaImagenes, "foto.jpg"); 
   
   uriImagenGuardada = Uri.fromFile(nombreImagen);
   intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriImagenGuardada);
   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
   
  }
```

So, the interesting part is to take the image from the camara and I should be able to display it on the screen with an imageView. I think the code is running okay, but since I got this error, I am not sure:

Error below.

```
11-02 22:00:21.553: E/Hwmsen_sensors(720): hwmsen: rotationvector -34177 
11-02 22:00:21.749: E/Hwmsen_sensors(720): hwmsen: rotationvector -33323 
11-02 22:00:21.949: E/Hwmsen_sensors(720): hwmsen: rotationvector -32778 
11-02 22:00:22.149: E/Hwmsen_sensors(720): hwmsen: rotationvector -32985 
11-02 22:00:22.351: E/Hwmsen_sensors(720): hwmsen: rotationvector -32589 
11-02 22:00:22.549: E/Hwmsen_sensors(720): hwmsen: rotationvector -32711 
11-02 22:00:22.754: E/Hwmsen_sensors(720): hwmsen: rotationvector -32748 
11-02 22:00:22.915: E/Sensors(720): new acc setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000) err! go to hwmsen
11-02 22:00:23.111: E/Hwmsen_sensors(720): hwmsen: rotationvector -33314
```

Comment: Are you sure that is all there is to that error log?

Comment: I have just debugged the Application again. I edited the post with the error, sorry for my mistake. Any ideas anyway ? Thank you

Comment: By the way, I place the "breakpoint" in the line where I decode the file, just to infrom you. Thank you

Comment: there is no error in these logs. maybe take out the break point and post them??

Comment: Indeed. As you said there was any error in there. I just changed the "takePhoto" class and the way of decoding the file. I just took the data using "data.getExtras()". Now it seems it works.